# SQL - Insert Into Table If Exists in sys.databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a main database with a table called `ERTdata` where the name of databases are stored and I am after columns `Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate` in this database.

I have another table called `DatabasesOnServer` with columns `Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate`.

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseOnServer (Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby,CreatedDate)
    SELECT Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate 
    FROM ERTdata 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM sys.databases   
                  WHERE name = ERTdata.DatabaseName)
```

The above query checks if the server already has the particular database on it and if the same is present in ERTdata, it inserts into table DatabaseOnServer.

The problem is it causes duplicates. How can we insert it only if it does not exist and if the database is not present on server delete the entry from `DatabaseOnServer`.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is it causes duplicates. How can we insert it only if it does not exist and if the database is not present on server delete the entry from DatabaseOnServer.

You could simply use `EXCEPT`:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseOnServer (Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby,CreatedDate)
SELECT Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate 
FROM ERTdata 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM sys.databases   
              WHERE name = ERTdata.DatabaseName)
EXCEPT
SELECT Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate 
FROM  DatabaseOnServer;
```

**EDIT:**

> However, How can I delete the record from DatabaseOnServer if a database gets deleted. Example: I have a database called ABC, The name and details gets inserted on DatabaseOnServer. I delete the ABC from server and the entry is still present in DatabaseOnServer. The record should be deleted

```
MERGE DatabaseOnServer AS trg
USING (SELECT Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate 
       FROM ERTdata 
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM sys.databases   
                     WHERE name = ERTdata.DatabaseName)) AS src
ON trg.Id = src.id AND trg.DatabaseName = src.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate )
   VALUES (Id, DatabaseName, Initiatedby, CreatedDate )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
   DELETE;
```

Comment: Hello lad2025, The query works. However, How can I delete the record from DatabaseOnServer if a database gets deleted.

Example: I have a database called ABC, The name and details gets inserted on DatabaseOnServer. I delete the ABC from server and the entry is still present in DatabaseOnServer. The record should be deleted

Comment: @Tango This should be whole new question. If you need more logic use `MERGE`.

Comment: @Tango Please do not change question that way. If your original question is solved then mark as accepted and ask new one.